# how do I fit 3D data

Tags: numpy, scipy

I have a list of 3D points, and I want to fit the to a sphere:

```
R^2 = (x-x0)^2 + (y-y0)^2 + (z-z0)^2
```

So I thought, I'd express z, and fit 2D data with 4 parameters (x0, y0, z0 and R):

```
z = sqrt(R^2 - (x-x0)^2 - (y-y0)^2) + z0
```

Here's a code (it is a part of larger project):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from scipy import *
from scipy.optimize import leastsq

Coordinates = load("data.npy")

xyCoords = Coordinates[:, [0, 1]]
zCoords  = Coordinates[:, 2]

p0 = [149.33499, 148.95999, -218.84893225608857, 285.72893713890107]

fitfunc = lambda p, x: sqrt(p[3]**2 - (x[0] - p[0])**2 - (x[1] - p[1])**2) + x[2]
errfunc = lambda p, x, z: fitfunc(p, x) - z
p1, flag = leastsq(errfunc, p0, args=(xyCoords, zCoords))

print p1
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2) (1404)
```

Here's a link to [data.npy](http://wikisend.com/download/159798/data.npy).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to properly define your `fitfunc`:

```
fitfunc = lambda p, x: sqrt(p[3]**2 - (x[:, 0] - p[0])**2 - (x[:, 1] - p[1])**2) + p[2]
```

I don't think that your approach is very robust, because when you take the `sqrt` there are two solutions, one positive, one negative, and you are only considering the positive. So unless all your points are on the top half of a sphere, your approach will not work. It is probably better to make `r` your fitfunc:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import leastsq

# test data: sphere centered at 'center' of radius 'R'
center = (np.random.rand(3) - 0.5) * 200
R = np.random.rand(1) * 100
coords = np.random.rand(100, 3) - 0.5
coords /= np.sqrt(np.sum(coords**2, axis=1))[:, None]
coords *= R
coords += center

p0 = [0, 0, 0, 1]

def fitfunc(p, coords):
    x0, y0, z0, R = p
    x, y, z = coords.T
    return np.sqrt((x-x0)**2 + (y-y0)**2 + (z-z0)**2)

errfunc = lambda p, x: fitfunc(p, x) - p[3]

p1, flag = leastsq(errfunc, p0, args=(coords,))

>>> center
array([-39.77447344, -69.89096249,  44.46437355])
>>> R
array([ 69.87797469])
>>> p1
array([-39.77447344, -69.89096249,  44.46437355,  69.87797469])
```

Comment: @Adobe Because `coords` has shape `(100, 3)`, but `coords.T` has shape `(3, 100)`, and so it unpacks one row into each variable when you do `x, y, z = coords.T`.

Comment: Oh, that's cool. I did `zCoords  = Coordinates[:, 2]` for simular thing.

Comment: I'll open a bounty tomorrow -- I want to reward Your answer.