# why is list of tuple failing as an argument for optimize.leasztsq?

Tags: python, scipy, format, least-squares

I use the function leastsq from scipy.optimize to fit sphere coordinates and radius from 3D coordinates.

So my code looks like this :

```
def distance(pc,point):

    xc,yc,zc,rd = pc
    x ,y ,z     = point
    return np.sqrt((xc-x)**2+(yc-y)**2+(zc-z)**2)

def sphere_params(coords):

    from scipy import optimize

    err = lambda pc,point : distance(pc,point) - pc[3]

    pc = [0, 0, 0, 1]
    pc, success = optimize.leastsq(err, pc[:], args=(coords,))

    return pc
```

(Built thanks to : [how do I fit 3D data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785428/how-do-i-fit-3d-data).)

I started working with the variable coords as a list of tuples (each tuple being an x,y,z coordinate):

```
>> coords
>> [(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(-1,0,0),(0.57,0.57,0.57),...,(1,0,0),(0,1,0)]
```

Which lead me to an error :

```
>> pc = sphere_params(coords)
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/home/michel/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 374, in leastsq
     raise TypeError('Improper input: N=%s must not exceed M=%s' % (n, m))
TypeError: Improper input: N=4 must not exceed M=3
```

Where N is the number of parameters stored in pc, and M the number of data points. Which makes it look like I haven't given enough data points while my list coords actually regroups 351 tuples versus 4 parameters in pc !

From what I read in minipack the actual culprit seems to be this line (from _check_func()) :

```
res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
```

Unless i'm mistaken, in my case it translates into

```
res = atleast_1d(distance(*(pc[:len(pc)],) + args)
```

But I'm having a terrible time trying to understand what this mean alongs with the rest of the _check_func() function.

I ended up changing coords into an array before giving it as an argument to `sphere_param()` : `coords = np.asarray(coords).T` and it started working just fine. I would really like to understand why the data format was giving me trouble though !

In advance, many thanks for your answers!

EDIT : I notice my use of coords for the "distance" and "err" functions was **really** unwise and misleading, it wasn't so in my original code so it was not the core of the problem. Now make more sense.

Comment: Your distance function unpacks coords as `x, y, z = [(x0, y0, z0), (x1, y1, z1), (x2, y2, z2), (x3, y3, z3), etc]`, which will take the first emlement of the list to `x`, the second to `y`, and the third to `z` but your list is actually quite longer than that. That is, it will try to set `x` to `(x0, y0, z0)`. What you want is `x, y, z = zip(coords)` which will do the same thing as transposing. I am not sure why you didn't get `ValueError: too many values to unpack`

Comment: You also have a typo in your `distance` function: in `xc,yx,zx,rd = pc`, I think `yx` and `zx` should be `yc` and `zc`.

Comment: yikes, you're totally right about those yc and zc, thanks. Regarding your previous point, I think the leastsq() function sends the element of args (so that would be the tuples(x0, y0, z0), (x1, y1, z1), (x2, y2, z2), (x3, y3, z3 ), etc ) one by one to my lambda function I called "err". So I expect distance() to also receive pc and only one tuple, not the full list.

Comment: Hm, I think it just unpacks `args`, which is a tuple around `coords` in its entirety, so it passes `args = (coords,)` as `err(pc, *args)` which is equivalent to `err(pc, args[0], ...)`, which in turn is `err(pc, coords)` since `len(args)` is `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `err` function must take the full list of coords and return a full list of distances. `leastsq` will then take the list of errors, square and sum them, and minimize that squared sum.

There are also distance functions in [`scipy.spatial.distance`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html), so I would recommend that:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
from scipy.optimize import leastsq

def distance_cdist(pc, coords):
    return cdist([pc], coords).squeeze()

def distance_norm(pc, points):
    """ pc must be shape (D+1,) array
        points can be (N, D) or (D,) array """
    c = np.asarray(pc[:3])
    points = np.atleast_2d(points)
    return np.linalg.norm(points-c, axis=1)

def sphere_params(coords):
    err = lambda pc, coords: distance(pc[:3], coords) - pc[3]
    pc = [0, 0, 0, 1]
    pc, success = leastsq(err, pc, args=(coords,))
    return pc

coords = [(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(-1,0,0),(0.57,0.57,0.57),(1,0,0),(0,1,0)]
sphere_params(coords)
```

Comment: Although that distance function is quite appealing I need to be able to operate distance on point vs array and point vs point. The second case would fail so I'm gonna stick with the 'mathematic' solution for the moment. I'll see if I can make it work without too much hair-pulling once everything else is settled !

Comment: what I was looking for is actually : np.linalg.norm(a-b,axis=1). That should get everyone happy ! edit : aouch no it doesn't with point-point distance :/

Comment: That's true if you don't give an axis, linalg.norm(a) with a being a matrix returns the norm of the matrix. linalg.norm(a,axis =1) however gives you the norm of each column hence linalg.norm(a-b,axis =1) with b being the coordinates of the point from which you want the distance. Sadly, it doesn't work if both a and b are simple coordinate vectors.

Comment: Yes, that's what the `np.atleast_2d` is for. Alternatively, you could use `axis=-1`, which may be faster anyway, but you'll have to convert to `array` at some point anyway to do the difference.

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't used this function much, as best I can tell, `coords` is passed as is to your `distance` function.  At least it would if the error checking allowed.  In fact it is likely that the error checking tries to do that, and raises an error if `distance` raises an error.  So lets try that.

```
In [91]: coords=[(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(-1,0,0),(0.57,0.57,0.57),(1,0,0),(0,1,0)]

In [92]: distance([0,0,0,0],coords)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-92-113da104affb> in <module>()
----> 1 distance([0,0,0,0],coords)

<ipython-input-89-64c557cd95e0> in distance(pc, coords)
      2 
      3         xc,yx,zx,rd = pc
----> 4         x ,y ,z     = coords
      5         return np.sqrt((xc-x)**2+(yc-y)**2+(zc-z)**2)
      6 

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

So that's where the 3 comes from - your `x, y, z = coords`.

```
distance([0,0,0,0],np.array(coords))
```

same error.

```
distance([0,0,0,0],np.array(coords).T)
```

gets past that issue (3 rows that can be split into 3 variables), raises another error: `NameError: name 'yc' is not defined`

That looks like a typo in the code you gave us, !naughty, naughty!.

Correcting that:

```
In [97]: def distance(pc,coords):

        xc,yc,zc,rd = pc
        x ,y ,z     = coords
        return np.sqrt((xc-x)**2+(yc-y)**2+(zc-z)**2)
   ....: 

In [98]: distance([0,0,0,0],np.array(coords).T)
Out[98]: array([ 0.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  0.98726896,  1.        ,  1.        ])

# and wrapping the array in a tuple, as `leastsq` does
In [102]: distance([0,0,0,0],*(np.array(coords).T,))
Out[102]: array([ 0.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  0.98726896,  1.        ,  1.        ])
```

I get a 5 element array, one value for each 'point' in `coords`.  Is that what you want?

Where did you get the idea that `leastsq` feeds your `coords` one tuple at a time to your `lambda`?

> args : tuple
>           Any extra arguments to func are placed in this tuple.

In general with these `optimize` functions, it you want to perform the operation on a set of conditions, then you need to iterate over those conditions, calling the optimize on each one.  Or if you want to optimize over the whole set at once, then you need to write your function (err,etc) to work with the whole set at once.

Comment: Hmm as you and askewchan said "leastsq" does feed my lambda in one time, not sure why I thought it would feed one at a time anymore ! However my question was more about the failure of "leastsq" which happens before "distance" is even called (which would also be a failure !).  I don't understand why res = atleast_1d(distance(*(pc[:len(pc)],) + args) fails with list of tuple and not with an array, I should probably pull my hair a little more though, Thanks anyway !

Comment: I'm puzzled as to why `_check_func` returned without an error, allowing `leastsq` to do the `n>m` test and raise its own TypeError.  I'd have to study the calling sequence more.

Comment: When I try to run your code, I keep getting `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)` - the error in your `distance` function.  I wonder if your `scipy` version has a `try` block that lets it escape and return the `TypeError`.

Comment: Distance runs fine with arrays for me, have you made sure coords.shape = (3,N) ? I seriously hope I haven't made another typo !

Comment: My last comment was about the list ersion

Answer (score 0):

So here is what I came up with from previous help :

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import leastsq

def a_dist(a,B):
    # works with - a : reference point - B : coordinates matrix
    return np.linalg.norm(a-B, axis=1) 

def parametric(coords):

    err = lambda pc,point : a_dist(pc,point) - 18

    pc = [0, 0, 0] # Initial guess for the parameters
    pc, success = leastsq(err, pc[:], args=(coords,))

    return pc
```

It definitely works with both a list of tuples and an array of shape (N,3)

```
>>  cluster #it's more than 6000 point you won't have the same result
>>  [(4, 30, 19), (3, 30, 19), (5, 30, 19), ..., (4, 30, 3), (4, 30, 35)]
>>  sphere_params(cluster)
>>  array([ -5.25734467,  20.73419249,   9.73428766])

>>  np.asarray(cluster).shape
>>  (6017,3)
>>  sphere_params(np.asarray(cluster))
>>  array([ -5.25734467,  20.73419249,   9.73428766])
```

Combining this version with Askewchan's, ie having :

```
def sphere_params(coords):
    err = lambda pc, coords: distance(pc[:3], coords) - pc[3]
    pc = [0, 0, 0, 1]
    pc, success = leastsq(err, pc, args=(coords,))
    return pc
```

Also works fine, to be honest I didn't take the time to try your solution. I definitely stopped taking the radius as a fit parameter however. I found it not robust at all (even 6000 -noisy- data points were not enough to get the right curvature !).

When comparing to my first code I'm still not quite sure what was wrong though, I probably messed up with global/local variables although I really don't recall using any "global" statement in any of my functions.